# Problem with the algorithm

Tags: algorithms, graphs, backtracking

I am trying to execute the following algorithm shown in the image from my course slide.  I am trying to get the table shown in the image:

[image: Backtracking Algorithm]

1st Iteration
L2: 1:CS=A, SL = A, NSL = A
L3: while NSL!=[]: true
L4:
L6:no children: false
L17:NSL =BCDA
L18:CS:=B
L19:SL=BA
L20, L21
2nd Iteration
L3:While NSL (true)
L4:
L6:no children: false
L17: NSL=EFBCDA
L18: CS:=E
L19:SL:= EBA
L20, L21
3rd Iteration
L3:while NSL (true)
L4:
L6:no children: false
L17:NSL= HIEFBCDA
L18: CS:= H
L19:SL:=HEBA
L20, L21

At this point its fine but when there are no more children of current node, it has to backtrack, so it should execute the while loop, at that point I am losing the track:
L3:while NSL(true)
L4:
L6:no children: true
L7:begin
L8:while SL is not empty (true) and CS:=H
L9: DE=H
L10:SL=EBA
L11:NSL=IEFBCDA
L12:CS=I
L14:SL= IEBA

Now it should keep traversing the while loop but I am having problem with this. Somebody please correct this algorithm or guide me a better backtracking algorithm which has the contents of table.

Zulfi.

Comment: Please credit the source of all copied material.

Comment: I have added its the content of my course slide. I don't know beyond that.

Comment: You presumably know which course it is, where it is taught, and who teaches it. Add that, please.